# how to save image to database table through web api in swift

Tags: swift, image

I am building an app using Swift 3.0 for study purpose.
One of the functions is to fetch and save data from(to) SQL Server database tables. One of the columns is to store IMAGE(photo) in table: data type in table is Image (`system.Byte[]`) in **SQL Server**.

I can get the photo column through web api and show it in Image component like this:

```
let encodedImageData = My web api url
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: encodedImageData   options: .allZeros)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
let imageView.image = image
```

I had problem to save the Image to the database through web api (can save other columns, but had problem with Image column).
I tried this:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) as NSData?
```

but failed.

my web api and invoke as below:

```
func post(parameters : Dictionary<String, String>, urlString : String) {


    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error: \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
                let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  // Okay, the `json` is here, let's get the value for 'success' out of it
                print("Success: \(success)")
            } else {
                let jsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)    // No error thrown, but not dictionary
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                          // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume()


}

@IBAction func insert(){

 let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimageview.image!) as NSData?

 post(parameters: ["Name": nametxt.text!,"Address": addresstxt.text!,"photoname": photonametxt.text!,"photo": String(describing: imageData),"url": urltxt.text! ], urlString: "http://XXXXXXX/api/myfavorites")

}
```

Can someone help me have a look at image save method to database table in Swift?

Comment: Please show the code of your web API call; also tell us in which (transfer) format the web server expects the image data

Comment: @AndreasOetjen: I have added the web api. In the web server SQL Server database table, the column for image(photo) is IMAGE format - Byte[]. Thanks!

Comment: Does it has any error return from server?

Comment: No errors: Success nil. No data was inserted into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong data structure for your image. Instead of using `NSData` and `String(describing:)` (which definitely does not do what you want), you should directly use a *base64 encoded string*, like the following code:

```
@IBAction func insert(){

    let imageBase64String = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimageview.image!)?.base64EncodedString()

    post(parameters: ["Name": nametxt.text!,"Address": addresstxt.text!,"photoname": photonametxt.text!,"photo": imageBase64String,"url": urltxt.text! ], urlString: "http://XXXXXXX/api/myfavorites")

}
```